# What is an antonym for "sin"?

Tags: nouns, antonyms

I need to know the opposite of *sin*, other than *virtue* which I don't think is right.

Comment: How are you defining "sin"?

Comment: Why don't you think *virtue* is right? The Seven Deadly Sins are counterbalanced by the [Seven Heavenly Virtues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_virtues#Seven_heavenly_virtues).

Comment: What makes you think _virtue_ is not right? For the most common interpretations of sin, it _is_ the antonym, so you seem to use a non-standard definition of sin. Please tell us :)

Comment: I think the OP is thinking of *a sin* as an act as in "to commit a sin" and *a virtue* as a trait as in "he has many virtues".  Possibly what is needed is a single word for a virtuous act.

Comment: What @Rupe said. The word ***sin*** has different meanings to different people. Unless OP specifies exactly what it means to *him*, I think the question is Unclear.

Comment: Please use the site search before asking. It's much faster than typing up an entire question, too.

Comment: Why would it have to have an antonym? There seems a presumption by many contributors to this site that language is like Newton's second law of motion, i.e. that for every action there is an equal and opposite reaction.

Comment: It is impeccant or without sin;        faultless

Answer (score 1):

How about ***righteousness***?

right·eous·ness  [rahy-chuhs-nis]  Show IPA
noun
1.
the quality or state of being righteous.
2.
righteous conduct.
3.
the quality or state of being just or rightful: They came to realize the righteousness of her position on the matter.

righteous  (ˈraɪtʃəs)

— adj
1.  a. characterized by, proceeding from, or in accordance with accepted standards of morality, justice, or uprightness; virtuous: a righteous man
    b. ( as collective noun ; preceded by the ): the righteous
2.  morally justifiable or right, esp from one's own point of view: righteous indignation

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/righteousness

Answer (score 0):

[***good deed***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deed) maybe?

> deed: something that is done, performed, or accomplished; act: *a good deed*

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking Christian theology, and *sin* as mass noun rather than the countable noun or verb, I would suggest *[grace](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/state+of+grace)* as a possible antonym.